# Error occur when try to delete via select #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I`m trying to delete a lot of data via select. This select work appropriate and returns in result 75k+ rows. I need to delete them, but when I try to delete it this error occurs

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s). I'm using PHPMyAdmin.

```
DELETE FROM `crm_wsal_metadata`
WHERE `occurrence_id` = ANY

(SELECT *
FROM `crm_wsal_metadata`
WHERE `name` = `PostDate` AND `value` BETWEEN str_to_date('2018-12-26', '%Y-%m-%d') AND str_to_date('2020-05-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY `occurrence_id`)
```

Comment: Your query is malformed.  You have `select *` but in an aggregation query.  `GROUP BY` *summarizes multiple rows* into a single row.  However, you have no summarization functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
... SELECT `occurence_id` ...
```

instead of `SELECT *`. The `group by` clause forces you to use only grouped columns and aggregations, not star (perhaps unless some proprietary quirks I don't recommend to rely on).

Answer (score 0):

I had found the answer and will try to write it step by step:

1. Why does this error happen?

> In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
>   This behavior is documented at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

2. How to make such thing happen?

There are two ways:

---

1. Join the table to itself

`UPDATE tbl AS a
INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON ....
SET a.col = b.col`

---

2. Nest the subquery deeper into a from clause

`UPDATE tbl SET col = (
  SELECT ... FROM (SELECT.... FROM) AS x);`

---

Personally, in my case the code looked like this:


`DELETE FROM crm_wsal_metadata 
WHERE occurrence_id = ANY (
SELECT occurrence_id FROM (
SELECT occurrence_id FROM crm_wsal_metadata WHERE name = "PostDate" AND value BETWEEN str_to_date('2018-12-26', '%Y-%m-%d') AND str_to_date('2020-05-31', '%Y-%m-%d') AS search) )`

Sorry for such bad styling. Im new with it :)